# Fancybox JQuery not loading

Tags: php, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm having trouble with loading the JQuery for Fancybox. I really have no idea what is going wrong.

```
<!-- FAVICON + CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>images/ftimagesoriginal/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>styles/layout.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>styles/menu.css"/>


    <!-- JQUERY FANCYBOX + CSS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?"/>


    <!-- JQUERY MENU -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

The code above is in my MAIN_MASTER page, in my 'home.php' page I'm requesting the .fancybox function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
JQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

The code below is an example of an image with Fancybox.

```
<li><a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>images/ftimagesoriginal/ft1.jpg"><img src="<?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>images/ftimagesresized/ft1174.jpg" alt="test"/></a></li>
```

I really have no idea what is going on. I checked the order of loading the JQuery libs, I checked the console in Chrome and I'm getting the 'Uncaught referenceError: JQuery is not defined' error. All of my JQuery libs are loading so the browser finds them on my server.

Can anyone help me resolving my problem? I'm affraid it's just a very stupid mistake, but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //JQuery is replaced by $
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

Comment: Tried that one before, it solves the Uncaught ... error, but Fancybox still won't open.

Comment: can you create a fiddle? or can you check in console if you see anything? By the way, what does the following render? <?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>images/ftimagesoriginal/ft1.jpg